# how to add strings from different arrays into one array in java

Tags: java

Hello I'm a bit confused with some coding problem I am trying to solve.

I have a few string arrays:

```
String[] firstNames= {"Fred","John","Amir", "James","Bob","Jay","Amber"};
String[] lastNames = {"Bond","Kates","Memar", "White","Marley","Brown","Nogofski"};
String[] idNumbers = {"R111111","A222222","AB11111", "KR22121","V311133","L242434","P102432"};
String[] employeeNum = {"1111","2222","3333", "4444","5555","6666","7777"};
```

I have to create one array and somehow organize the corresponding pieces of information provided above in the method `Employee[] list = new Employee[firstNames.length]; 
list = listOfEmployees(firstNames,lastNames,idNumbers); // create the list of employees in one array`

I started writing out the method:

```
public static Employee[] listOfEmployees(String[] firstName, String[]             
lastName, String[] idNumber){

}
```

but not sure how to approach this. also not sure if my parameters are correct.

the end result is supposed to look like this:

```
Employee #1 
    first name:Fred Last Name:Bond
    Id number:R111111
```

.
.
.

```
Employee #2 
    first name:John Last Name:Kates
    Id number:A222222
```

and so on..

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

Employee class:

```
public class Employee{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String idNumber;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private int employeeCount;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param firstName first name
     * @param lastName last name
     * @param idNumber id number 
     */
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String idNumber){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        employeeCount = 0;
    }
    /**
     * Accessors here
     */

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getIdNumber(){
        return idNumber;
    }

    public String getEmployeeNumber(){
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    // mutators here

    /**
     * @param firstName first name
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName last name
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /** 
     * @param idNumber id number
     */
    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber){
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param employeeNumber employee number
     */
    public void setEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber){
        this.employeeNumber = "";
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result = "First name: " + getFirstName() + "\nLast name: " + getLastName()
                + "\nId number: " + getIdNumber() + "\nEmployee number: ";
        if(getEmployeeNumber() == null){
        return result + "No employee number has been assigned yet!";
    }
        return result + getEmployeeNumber();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the defintion of the Employee class

Comment: @QPaysTaxes i tried several `for` loops but couldnt tie them together.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i have the employee class but its quite long, wasnt sure if to add or not.

Comment: If the purpose of  `employeeCount` is to keep track of how many instances are being created then you should declare  it as a `static` variable.

Comment: My OCD is telling me I don't like this Datastructure. I am not sure why you group all names to names-array, lname to lnam-array etc.. Its not code friendly and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
private static Employee[] listOfEmployees(String[] firstNames, String[] lastNames, String[] idNumbers){     
   Employee[] list = new Employee[firstNames.length]; 

   for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    list[i]=new Employee(firstNames[i], lastNames[i], idNumbers[i]);
   }    

  return list;
 }
```

To print the array returned by the above function, you may use:

```
private static void printEmployees(Employee[] employees){
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        System.out.println("ID: "+employee.getIdNumber());
        System.out.println("Name : "+employee.getFirstName()+" "+employee.getLastName());
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

And call them by following statement:

`printEmployees(listOfEmployees(firstNames,lastNames,idNumbers));`

Comment: Will crash if the arrays do not have the same size though.. Edit: More precisely if firstNames length is higher that another array length

Comment: Sure @SnoozeTime but for this simple scenario and problem that (variable sizes of individual array or any of them is null or not ) has not been considered. Should we? What do you think?

Comment: If the code is shared with other people, I'm pretty sure someone is going to call this function with arrays of different size. Of course if the code is just a simple scenarios, it should be ok =)

Comment: @SanjeevSaha how would i go about printing these?

Comment: Would you like to print the array of `Employee` on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Do a for loop and use the Employee constructor to initialize the objects:

```
Employee[] list = new Employee[firstNames.length];
for (int i = 0; i < firstName.length; i++) {
    list[i] = new Employee(firstName[i], lastName[i] ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
String[] firstNames= {"Fred","John","Amir", "James","Bob","Jay","Amber"};
String[] lastNames = {"Bond","Kates","Memar", "White","Marley","Brown","Nogofski"};
String[] idNumbers = {"R111111","A222222","AB11111", "KR22121","V311133","L242434","P102432"};
String[] employeeNum = {"1111","2222","3333", "4444","5555","6666","7777"};
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<firstName.length();i++){
list.add(new(Employee(firstName[i],lastName[i],idNumbers[i],employeeNumber[i]))}

}}
```